# Microsoft.Build Unable to Locate SDK or SDK Resolver

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm trying to automate some solution and project file updates using the [Microsoft.Build](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build/) package, but have been encountering problems such as `the SDK Resolver folder exists but without an SDK Resolver DLL or manifest file.` I also got an error about not being able to find `Microsoft.Net.SDK` which unfortunately I didn't capture.

Eventually I got a little farther by adding a reference to [Microsoft.Build.Runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Runtime/), but then I got `Could not load SDK Resolver. A manifest file exists, but the path to the SDK Resolver DLL file could not be found`.

All the answers I can find are about runtime errors in existing build systems rather than utilizing the MSBuild libraries directly.

How can I use Microsoft.Build to access project files programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the answer is located in a sensible place in Microsoft's documentation ("Use MSBuild Programmatically"), except the name of the page itself is not intuitive. It's titled [Update to MSBuild 15](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/updating-an-existing-application?view=vs-2019#use-microsoftbuildlocator) and gives the following solution:

- Reference Microsoft.Build.Locator ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Locator/)/[GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/MSBuildLocator/))
- In the `PackageReference` for `Microsoft.Build`, add `ExcludeAssets="runtime"`

  - Easy to remember because MSBuildLocator will cause a compile-time error if this is not done
- Call `MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();` in your code prior to calling any methods which use MSBuild

Example from a working csproj:

```xml
...
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build" Version="16.8.0">
      <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator" Version="1.4.1" />
...
```

More background can be found in [this GitHub Issue on the MSBuild repo](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/2427). To my understanding, the MSBuild tool locations used to be stored in the registry, and the Microsoft.Build library still looks there, but when support was added for side-by-side installations of Visual Studio SKUs this was no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks @PerryQian-MSFT - this was my first time documenting my own answer on SO, so I hadn't thought of that.